# WebRequest fails over TLS 1.1 / 1.2 for Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net, ssl

I"m running a .net 4.5 application which makes secure outbound requests to an external server supporting only TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2. All goes fine when i run the application from windows 8/8.1 host, but on Windows Server 2008 is fails with: 
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

I believe that .net rely on underling OS infrastructure and because Windows Server 2008 does not support TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 the WebRequest also fails. Can somebody confirm that? Any documentation to point me to?

Code sample:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://SOMEURL");
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
         // read the stream
    }
}
```

I'm also setting the supported protocols:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245030

Comment: I have same error on my Windows Server 2012 R2, How did you fix it?

Comment: Hi @SavasAdar. The issue i had was specifically tight to Windows Server 2008. TLS 1.1 / 1.2 are supported at OS level on Windows Server 2008 R2 and the newer versions, so the root of your problem is not related to the one i had. NOTE: did you enable TLS 1.1 / 1.2 protocols by ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol ?

Comment: Yes I enabled it but I still live this error.

Comment: If Windows Server 2008 gets SP2 installed, TLS 1.1 and 1.2 is may now be supported: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

> because Windows Server 2008 does not support TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 the WebRequest also fails.

Yes, this is the case.

> Any documentation to point me to?

From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245030:

```
Windows Server 2008 supports the following protocols:
 SSL 2.0
 SSL 3.0
 TLS 1.0

Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 support the following protocols:
 SSL 2.0
 SSL 3.0
 TLS 1.0
 TLS 1.1
 TLS 1.2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm looking for a document saying that .NET uses OS components and does not implement its own secure communication. For example on the same machine i'm able to do TLS 1.2 connections from Google Chrome browser because it does not rely on OS implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I found an indirect proof for you.

[SecurityProtocolType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.securityprotocoltype(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Specifies the security protocols that are supported by the Schannel security package.

[Support for SSL/TLS protocols on Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2011/10/02/support-for-ssl-tls-protocols-on-windows.aspx)

> Now let’s come to the point, on Windows the support for SSL/TLS protocols is tied to the SCHANNEL component. So, if a specific OS version doesn’t support a SSL/TLS version, this means it remains unsupported.

[Secure channel compatibility support with SSL and TLS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2011/10/07/secure-channel-compatibility-support-with-ssl-and-tls.aspx)