# Download Handler fails to download file from GitHub URL

Tags: c#, wpf, github

My program has an Update button that downloads the latest version zip from GitHub.

It worked for many months but now the progress bar no longer updates and it doesn't download a file from the GitHub Release URL.

However, I tested it with a Google Drive URL and it works, but URL naming convention won't be compatible with this project.

Is there a way to get around it with the code, or is does this have something to do with GitHub server rules?

[image: Update Window]

---

### Download Handlers

```
// Progress Changed
//
public void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Progress Bar
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        this.progressBar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
    }));
}


// Download Complete
//
public void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set the waiter Release
    // Must be here
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        waiter.Set();
    }));
}
```

---

### Download Method

In the actual code, the version number is a string that dynamically changes in the URL.

Doesn't Work:
https://github.com/MattMcManis/Glow/releases/download/v0.0.5.4-alpha/Glow.zip

Works:
https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1_7hzLR4FFZXK6qr2sP0uOleeB2GgtghE&export=download

```
public void StartDownload()
{
    // Start New Thread
    Thread worker = new Thread(() =>
    {
        waiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        Uri downloadUrl = new Uri("https://github.com/MattMcManis/Glow/releases/download/v0.0.5.4-alpha/Glow.zip);

        //Async
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(downloadUrl, tempDir + "Glow.zip");

        // Wait for Download to finish
        waiter.WaitOne();
    });

    // Start Download Thread
    worker.Start();
}
```

Comment: Where is `wc` defined/initialized?

Comment: @RonBeyer in the UpdateWindow Class. At the top, when the Window first opens. `public static WebClient wc = new WebClient();`. After `InitializeComponent()` it runs `StartDownload();`. It all used to work fine until just recently.

Comment: It is also possible you are getting an exception during the download causing your thread to terminate. Have you looked at the thread view to see if the thread is still running?

Comment: @RonBeyer Exception thrown: "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception." and "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Comment: @RonBeyer And "Safe handle has been closed."

Comment: Try setting the [`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491716/how-to-specify-ssl-protocol-to-use-for-webclient-class)

Comment: @RonBeyer It works and downloads now, thanks.

Comment: @RonBeyer I put `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` right before Async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On February 22, 2018 [GitHub disabled certain depreciated algorithms](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/). This causes the TLS  error that you are encountering.

The fix (as outlined in the comments) is to only allow `WebClient` to connect using TLS1.2 or higher. To do that, set the [`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) to `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` or higher.

I'm not sure why your progress bar would be showing "half" downloaded before it stopped, this error should pop up immediately when starting to download.

Comment: Actually the progress bar showed none, that was just a screenshot of when it was working.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make your URL from github to raw file.
Something like this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MattMcManis/Glow/releases/download/v0.0.5.4-alpha/Glow.zip