# Apps migrated from IIS server1 to another IIS server2 stopped communicating with an App on IIS server 1 via SSL (HTTPS)

Tags: .net, ssl, iis

Here's my scenario:

1. We have an IIS (8.5.9600.16384) server1 (Windows Server 2012) and apps on .net 4.6 on it
2. Apps (1) utilize WebApi app on IIS server1 via SSL
3. We built new Windows Server 2022 with IIS (10.0.20348.1)
4. We recompiled to .net 4.81 and migrated few apps from (1) to (3)
5. Apps (4) are able to utilize WebApi app on IIS server1 via SSL
6. We deployed new apps to server (3) - they are the same code base apps as apps (4) with only web.config different - connection string and few app related
7. Apps (6) are unable to utilize WebApi app on IIS server1 via SSL (HTTPS), but able via HTTP
8. We troubleshoot apps (4) and (6) with WireShark
9. Apps (4) are communicating with WebApi app on IIS server1 via SSL properly with TLS 1.2 doing handshake and all while apps (6) for some reason try to communicate with TLS 1.1 and GET REJECTED BY WebApi app on IIS server1

Any clue? We tried [How to specify SSL protocol to use for WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491716/how-to-specify-ssl-protocol-to-use-for-webclient-class) it didn't help and we don't want to go to that level. The fundamental question is what makes apps (4) to communicate with WebApi app on IIS server1 via SSL properly with TLS 1.2 while new ones doesn't. The code is the same! DNS records for apps (4) and (6) are resolving to server (3). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably a cipher mismatch. Install latest updates for 2012R2 (note that it's now out of support) and lastest updates for .NET. Set the registry settings as well to allow new ciphers (you can use the free IIS Crypto tool).

Comment: Server (3) is on Windows Server 2022 fully updated and on .net 4.81

Comment: No Server1 I mean

Comment: Thanks! We'll try. I'll let you know.

Comment: Do you think migrating App (2) to Server (3) might help? We planned that for later but maybe worth trying, so that we migrate it sooner if it helps?

Comment: Since the web app in (6) is the TLS client to talk to the old server, like the other commented, you need to check if any cipher mismatch occurred (should be clear from handshake packets). You should also check TLS client registry keys on the new server and the actual source code to identify more about why TLS v1.1 was chosen instead of v1.2, as those two are the common places for mistakes. The link was about `WebClient` which won't apply to `HttpClient`. So if you are using the latter you need to control it differently and search engines should have many articles on that topic.

Comment: Well yeah you should really have been off 2012 for some time already as it's out of support. A Wireshark trace will show you the Server Hello and Client Hello where you can look for mismatches. There needs to be at least one TLS version, one cipher and one hashing algorithm in common between them.

Comment: Thanks guys! I and dev ops incline that we need to migrate that app (3) on to the new server Windows Server 2022 where apps (4) (6) reside to see if it's going to help. Like I said we troubleshooted with WireShark and saw TLS 1.1 coming from apps 6 which is getting rejected and we saw TLS 1.2 coming from apps (4) which is NOT getting rejected. We also messed with regedit which disabled TLS 1/1.1 - that didn't help either. I kinda stopped believing WireShark having all this observed.

Comment: Our servers are virtualized and maybe VMs are malforming packets somehow? I also suggested dev ops to monitor packets leaving the new server Windows 2022 when apps (4) and (6) communicate with that WebApi app (2)

Still remains - The fundamental question is what makes apps (4) to communicate with WebApi app on IIS server1 via SSL properly with TLS 1.2 while new ones doesn't. The code is the same! DNS records for apps (4) and (6) are resolving to server (3). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Lex Li 5 hours ago - we don't control TLS in the source code. It's a highly complicated MVC app:

                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri($"{CmsConfiguration.Instance.MediaIdGeneratorUrl.Value}/{CmsConfiguration.Instance.MediaIdGeneratorRequestCount.Value}"));
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (responseStream != null)
...

Comment: the code above is how we invoke the webapi. throwing exceptions later when we touch responseStream

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.