# Cannot Enable TLS 1.2 on Windows Server 2008 SP2

Tags: .net, java-8, windows-server-2008, tls1.2

We have recently upgraded our Java version to `JDK 1.8.0_141` which is forcing our java client to use `TLS 1.2` and we have a `.Net 2.0` web service running on a `Windows Server 2008 SP2` which supports only `SSL V3` and `TLS 1.0`

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Standard
OS Version:                6.0.6002 Service Pack 2 Build 6002
```

So I've applied the patch `(Update for Windows Server 2008 (KB4019276))` from below KB to enable `TLS 1.1` and `TLS 1.2`

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows

And added below registry entries

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols\TLS 1.1]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

And restarted the box, but still the `.Net 2.0` web service is not supporting 
`TLS 1.2` but supports `TLS 1.1`. Tested using `TestSSLServer` (www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/)

```
TestSSLServer2.exe validation-service 443
Connection: validation-service:443
SNI: validation-service
  SSLv3:
     server selection: enforce server preferences
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  TLSv1.0:
     server selection: enforce server preferences
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  TLSv1.1: idem
```

Is there any config change needed to enable `TLS 1.2`? Or do I need to apply any other KB Patch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebRequest fails over TLS 1.1 / 1.2 for Windows Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479973/webrequest-fails-over-tls-1-1-1-2-for-windows-server-2008)